# Is there a Weibo share count endpoint

Tags: json, weibo

Long shot, but I'm looking for the Weibo version of these endpoints:

- https://graph.facebook.com/?id=https://www.google.com
- https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=https://www.google.com&format=json
- https://api.bufferapp.com/1/links/shares.json?url=https://www.google.com

I've had a fruitless few hours searching and can't get anything, and am hoping somebody here might know.

Answer (score 3):

Document: http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/statuses/count

API Request URL: https://api.weibo.com/2/statuses/count.json

API Request Methon: GET

API Request Parameter:

- access_token (required): get via OAuth.
- ids (required): the weibo id to be queried. It concatenate ids by comma and can exceed 100 ids.

API Response:

```
[
    {
        "id": "32817222",
        "comments": "16",
        "reposts": "38"
    },
   ...
]
```

API Response Parameters:

- **id** *(int64)*: the Weibo ID.
- **comments** *(int)*: the count of the comments
- **reposts** *(int)*: the count of the content be shared
- **attitudes** *(int)*: UNUSED

Comment: how do I get the Weibo share count for an article URL? (not Weibo post)

Comment: here is the full api document url: http://open.weibo.com/wiki/%E5%BE%AE%E5%8D%9AAPI. I think `short_url/shorten` and `short_url/share/counts` can achieve your purposes.